# Teltonika GPS first ACK using JAVA

Tags: java, gps

I am programing a Listener for Teltonika GPS. As you may know, Teltonika sends from the first time their IMEI, then Server needs to respond with a "01" for accepting the full raw data. So, I am stuck responding to GPS, here's my partial code:

```
DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
outToServer = new DataOutputStream(this.TCPSocket.getOutputStream());

byte[] msg = new byte[]{0x01};
outToServer.write(msg, 0, msg.length);
outToServer.flush();
```

Nothing happens, GPS is continuing to send me IMEI

Comment: That looks correct. What does your server application do afterwards? Does it acknowledge any AVL records you receive? Does it close the connection? Maybe the device is reconnecting, or it has some reason to think the connection is faulty, and therefor it resends its IMEI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference.

01 in binary is equals to byte value of 1.

```
byte[] msg = new byte[]{1};
outToServer.write(msg, 0, msg.length);
outToServer.flush();
```

Comment: I'm trying to ACK the message packets with the length of packets we receive. But it seems to be still waiting for a reply from the device log. Any clue?